# Getting the best variables from best subsets regression in R

Tags: r

I want to run best subset regression on a set of variables and then get the best 3 variables using R. I'm having problems obtaining the best 2 variables. I've included my code below.

```
set.seed(10)

a <- 1:100
b <- 1:100
c <- 1:100
d <- 1:100
e <- 1:100
f <- 1:100
g <- 1:100
h <- 1:100

data <- data.frame(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h)

library(leaps)

# best subsets regression
test <- regsubsets(a ~ b + c + d + e + f + g + h, data=data, nbest=4)
# nbest = 4, is the number of subsets of each size that is reported

# plot a table of models showing variables in each model.
summary(test)

# models are ordered by the selection statistic.
plot(test,scale="r2")

#get the variables that are important to the model
coef(test, 2)

#NOTE: THIS DOESN'T GIVE ME THE 2 BEST VARIABLES. IT ONLY GIVES ME THE BEST VARIABLE AT THE 2ND ITERATION. LOOK AT:
coef(test, 1:2)
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Best,
Dana

Comment: I'm a little confused by your example here, because all your variables are exactly the same.

Comment: You might want to provide real data.  With your current data, since all data is the same, all potential models will have the same goodness of fit, if they contain the same number of variables. This could be your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider an example with the built-in `mtcars` dataset:

```
test <- regsubsets(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars, nbest = 4)
```

This is the output from `summary(test)`:

```
summary(test)
# Subset selection object
# Call: regsubsets.formula(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars, nbest = 4)
# 10 Variables  (and intercept)
# <..snip..>
# 4 subsets of each size up to 8
# Selection Algorithm: exhaustive
#          cyl disp hp  drat wt  qsec vs  am  gear carb
# 1  ( 1 ) " " " "  " " " "  "*" " "  " " " " " "  " " 
# 1  ( 2 ) "*" " "  " " " "  " " " "  " " " " " "  " " 
# 1  ( 3 ) " " "*"  " " " "  " " " "  " " " " " "  " " 
# 1  ( 4 ) " " " "  "*" " "  " " " "  " " " " " "  " " 
# 2  ( 1 ) "*" " "  " " " "  "*" " "  " " " " " "  " " 
# 2  ( 2 ) " " " "  "*" " "  "*" " "  " " " " " "  " " 
# 2  ( 3 ) " " " "  " " " "  "*" "*"  " " " " " "  " " 
# 2  ( 4 ) " " " "  " " " "  "*" " "  "*" " " " "  " " 
# 3  ( 1 ) " " " "  " " " "  "*" "*"  " " "*" " "  " " 
# <..snip..>
```

The sets of coefficients are arranged by the number of independent variables, in subsets of 4 (what we indicated with the `nbest` argument); hence, `coef(test, 1:4)` will return coefficients from models with one independent variable, `coef(test, 5:8)` will be those with two independent variables, and so on.  Within each subset, the "best" model comes first.  The "best" model with two independent variables will therefore be model 5:

```
coef(test, 5)
# (Intercept)         cyl          wt 
#   39.686261   -1.507795   -3.190972
```

Comment: Thank you Weihuang, this is exactly what I was trying to figure out! I guess I just didn't quite understand how to use coef() with the nbest argument, but thanks to your help now I do!

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.